# Stripe: Card accepted in Platform account but declined in Connected account at the same time

Tags: stripe-payments

We use Stripe Connect API to:

1. create customer + card in Platform account
2. clone the customer + card into Connected account
3. charge the card in Connected account

All steps are executed immidiately one after another.
Step 1. suceeds (the card is valid in Platform account), but step 2. fails with "card is declined".

The card is valid in platform Stripe account but declined in connected Stripe account, at the same time.

Stripe support didn't provided any useful info, they referred us to [declined card help page](https://support.stripe.com/questions/decline-code-do-not-honor):

> the only way to resolve this is to ask your customer to reach out to their card-issuing bank to look at the transaction and determine why it was declined.

Unfortunately, We cannot ask the customer to help us.

Did anyone else encountered similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

Declines are common and to be expected. They can be for a number of reasons (e.g. region of the connected account, card brand, supported merchant codes on the card, past card usage history and many more reasons) which are ultimately up to the card issuing bank.

To clarify, when you say

> Step 1. suceeds (the card is valid in Platform account),

Just because a card succeeds being attached to a Customer does not mean that that card should be expected to work successfully going forward. Goes back to that this is up to the issuing bank and the best thing to do is prompt your end customer to use a different card.